# How to put seconds/minutes on a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, subtraction

I want to select the users that is oline on the last 25 minutes, how to do it?
I'm using `NOW()-600`, i don't know how much seconds 600 is, it does not seem to be 600ms.

```
SELECT count(user_id) FROM users WHERE last_activity >= NOW()-600
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [MySQL date methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Probably in your case the [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Something like the following maybe?

```
SELECT count(user_id) FROM users WHERE last_activity >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 MINUTE)
```

Also [this site about intervals](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/) might help you as well.